# SAPUI5 error showing bound data

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

I have a problem showing the JSON data that I read. I worked with OData models/requests and bindings, but not with JSON models/requests.

My "list" from my "Master" view is empty, at the beginning and I fill it regularly with some auto-refresh tactic.
Now the problem I have is that the data isn't shown, although the "list" list has the Model bound to it.

Here is the "list":

```
<List  
       id="list"  
       mode="{device>/listMode}"  
       select="handleListSelect"  
       items="{Master}" >  
       <ObjectListItem  
            type="{device>/listItemType}"  
            press="handleListItemPress"  
            title="{Material}"  
            number="{TargetQ}"  
            numberUnit="{UM}" >  
            <attributes>  
                 <ObjectAttribute text="{DelivQ}" />  
            </attributes>  
            <firstStatus>  
                 <ObjectStatus  
                      text="{Master>OrderNo}"  
                      state="{path: 'OrderStatus',  
                           formatter: 'sap.ui.demo.myFiori.util.Formatter.statusState'}" />  
            </firstStatus>  
            <secondStatus>  
               <ObjectStatus  
                 text="{ path: 'OrderStatus',  
                      formatter: 'sap.ui.demo.myFiori.util.Formatter.statusText'}"  
                 state="{ path: 'OrderStatus',  
                      formatter: 'sap.ui.demo.myFiori.util.Formatter.statusState'}" />  
            </secondStatus>  
       </ObjectListItem>  
  </List>
```

I've tried defining the "items" element different ways: {/Master}, {Master}, no luck.
I've tried defining the data to show different ways: {Master>OrderNo}, {OrderNo}, {Master>/OrderNo}, no luck

I've checked that the model has the data bound:

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("Master").byId("list").getModel("Master").getData()[0].OrderNo  
"000100765931"
```

So the model is bound and has 2 items but the page still shows this :
Capture.JPG

Here is how I bind the data:

```
onOrdersSuccess : function (text) {  
       var view = sap.ui.getCore().byId("Master")  
       setTimeout(function() {  
            //view.getModel("Master").getData().push(text);  
            view.getModel("Master").setData([]);   
            view.getModel("Master").setData(text);   
            view.getModel("Master").updateBindings();  
       }, 1000);  
  }
```

Any ideas ?

Regards,
Marius

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.

> items="{Master>/}"

Thank you,
Marius